# Oracle IN clause with tuples using NHibernate components

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I've declared some entity (named `Employee`) with `FluentNHibernate` mapping using `CompositeId` and `ComponentCompositeIdentifier`. My component identifier (named `Person`) consists of two fields:

- LastName
- FirstName.

When I look for employees using single person, everything works great. I need to look for employees by list of persons:

```
var result = from em in Session.Query<Employee>() where persons.Contains(em.Person)
```

Is NHibernate able to generate some sort of tuple expressions, like that? I'm using Oracle database.

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE (FirstName, LastName) IN (('Guy', 'Himuro'), ('Karen', 'Colmenares'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely you need https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/2159 to make it work. So currently it's not supported in NHibernate 5.2.

Comment: Thank you, Roman! I suppose, this commit together with https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/2158 will solve my problem.

Comment: Nope. That one is needed for Criteria/QueryOver. [2159](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/2159) will suffice for LINQ/hql. You can verify if it works with this [binaries](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewLog.html?buildId=2448239&buildTypeId=NHibernate_NHibernateReleasePackage&tab=artifacts#%2FNHibernate-5.2.5)